# ExcelVBA_CurrentValuecu_Filter?

Tags: excel, vba

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english!

I want

fix100-->current column & last row nummber?

Cells(100, ActiveCell.Column))--->Cells(???, ActiveCell.Column))

```
Sub ExcelVBA_CurrentValuecu_Filter()
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(100, ActiveCell.Column)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub ExcelVBA_CurrentValuecu_Filter()
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp)). _
        AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The statement `.Cells(.Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp)` will find the last cell in your column that has data in it. I used a `With` block to properly qualify all the ranges you're using in your code. That's why there's a dot `.` in front of `.Cells`. This is the same as always writing `ActiveSheet.Cells`.

Comment: filter condition start  --- off  OK